# Express js Redirect cookies not sent

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I have 2 separate apps, let's call them Login & Dashboard. Both apps have a UI written in react and an express server.

In my Login app, when I make a POST from my Login UI, it hits the Login Express server to authenticate. Once authenticated, I set a cookie and redirect to my Dashboard url:

```
res.cookie(cookie.key, cookie.access_token, {
      path: '/',
      domain: cookie.domain,
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: cookie.rememberExpiry
    })

res.redirect(dashboard_url)
```

However when I use `req.cookies` in my dashboard app I don't see any cookies.

When I make the POST from my Login UI I do indeed see a network call stating response header:

`Set-Cookie: mycookie=cookievalue; Max-Age=28800; Domain=.local.myurl.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 03 Nov 2016 19:20:39 GMT; HttpOnly`

Note that as of this moment the time is Nov 3 2016, 11:28 GMT so its not an expiry issue.

To test I have edited my hosts file such that login.local.myurl.com & dashboard.local.myurl.com point to localhost.

Is there any reason why the req.cookies is not available in the Dashboard express app??

Comment: Can you see the cookies being sent with the request? Is the request for which no cookies are set a "regular" request, or an XHR request?

Comment: what do you mean by "can I see the cookies being sent with the request"? I see nothing when i log `req.cookies` in my dashboard express server. Iny my Login UI when I POST to the Login Express server, I see in my chrome network tab: POST 302 found with response headers set

Comment: In the network tab, look at the request being made from the dashboard and check if that request contains a `Cookie` header (to rule out that the `cookie-parser` middleware isn't being used properly).

Comment: It contains no cookie header

Comment: Okay, so is the request that's being made a regular request, or an XHR ("AJAX")-based request?

Comment: I am using isomorphic fetch from here: https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch

Comment: In that case, take a look at this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch#sending-cookies

Comment: @robertklep thank you you directed me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was 2 fold.

First I needed to set `credentials: 'same-origin'` on `fetch`, which is to say that I had to allow cookies to persist on the request library I was using.

Second, because my server and my client are essentially separate, a redirect on the server did not have the intended effect on the client. Hence I could not just `res.redirect` from the server response. instead I replaced the `res.redirect` line with `res.status(200).send()` and in my client code, I simply did `window.location.replace('http://dashboardurl.com')`.

Hope that helps anyone who has this issue in the future.

Comment: I am trying this approach, but I still don't see the cookies after navigating to my "dashboardurl.com"